# How to collect entries from a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have YAML files like the following:

```
position_details:

  star_performer:
    title: "Star Performer"
    description: ""

  idiot of year:
    title: "idiot of year"
    description: "The Idiot of year Award recognizes excellence in anti - social  collaboration on social platform ."
```

I need to collect the `title`s whose associated `description` is not present, for example from the file above I need to collect the title `"Star Performer"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean filter out? delete them? return them? collect them into an array?

Comment: Filter out means to collect them in any form .. either in array form or list.

Comment: When someone fixes your problem and answers your question - as in below fully tested code - it's usually considered good form to accept the answer.

Comment: I accept :) thanks to all

Comment: You have to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it :-)

Comment: Done that and thanks for telling me that feature :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean by filter you want to collect those titles

```
data = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('path/to/your.yml', __FILE__)))

positions_with_no_description = data["position_details"].each_value.collect do |pos| 
  pos["title"] if pos["description"].empty?
end
```

Per the comment of toro2k if you're using Rails you can substitute blank? for empty? to cover cases where there is no description key present.

Also this will give you an array `positions_with_no_description` that includes nil values. To eliminate them just call `compact!`

A concise version of the above could be:

```
filtered = data["position details"]
             .each_value
             .collect { |p| p["title"] if p["description"].blank? }
             .compact!
```

I have tested this on your test yml file and it works. The error was I had mistakenly used `"position_details"` whereas you'd put "position details" as your key - no underscore.

My exact code from IRB where I just tested this:

```
> data = YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../test.yml', __FILE__))
> data["position details"].each_value.collect { |x| x["title"] if x["description"].empty? }.compact!
> # => ["Star Performer"]
```

Comment: Pay attention that you will get a `NoMethodError` if `pos` has no `description` key. A safer alternative could be `if post['description'].nil? || pos['description'].empty?`, or, since OP is using Rails just `if post['description'].blank?`.

Comment: right - but this is for the case described in the q - where description key is present - if it's rails blank is nice, agreed :-)

Comment: Hi Richard,undefined method `each_value' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) is coming

Comment: is the yaml file exactly as above? and you've loaded it using YAML.load_file?

Comment: yup, some more entries are there which I have avoided and nothing else

Comment: the code will do what you need it to - just checking the syntax to load the YAML

Comment: @cyborg This code is perfectly fine, if you get that no method error, probably `position_details` is mispelled somewhere.

Comment: Yes it's exactly waht toro2k just said - i just copied your file and corrected and it works fine - the key is to make sure your labels in the yaml are the same strings as used in the query... for example in your yaml you have ```"position details"``` and I had used the key "position_details" etc.